# How can I fit this Joint around this arm perfectly?

Tags: modeling, shrinkwrap

[image]I am modelling a robotic arm and have created a joint to attatch onto the bottom however ive run into a little problem. How can i wrap this joint around the arm perfectly without having to apply my mirror modifier? [enter image description here](https://i.sta)

[image]ck.imgur.com/XRC2C.png
[image]

Comment: Hello, how is it supposed to look once you've wrapped the joint around the arm?

Comment: Hello. I have added a picture of the reference to give a better idea of what the end result should look like